# VirtualBox not filling screen / Guest additions not inserted - already tried all the tricks I found

Tags: virtualbox, guest-additions

I have Windows 8, VirtualBox 5, Mint Cinnamon, and I am blocked with a small screen.
I've tried all the tricks I found on the web

I do:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms
```

I get:

> virtualbox-guest-dkms is already the newest version.
>   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 135 not upgraded.

When I do

`Devices` -> `Insert Guest Additions CD image`

I get:

> Could not mount the media/drive 'C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxGuestAdditions.iso' (VERR_PDM_MEDIA_LOCKED

I click the `Force Unmount` button, restart but still nothing.

I also gave max memory to the video display (128M)

Somewhere I noted the following error (can't remember at what juncture):

> Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
>   Component: ExtPackManagerWrap
>   Interface: IExtPackManager {edba9d10-45d8-b440-1712-46ac0c9bc4c5}

Last time I had these symptoms I started back from scratch with a fresh VM. But I can't do that every time.

Comment: Try to install a Iso mounting utility like virtual clone drive in your host OS,  mount the virtual box addon Iso via VCD, then make the virtual cd drive available to your VM and it should work.

Comment: @Richie086 : thanks for answering. I installed virtual clonedrive  and tried to use it to open the files I have related to Oracle Virtual box. All gave the same answer: "Error: can't open VCD!". I have 2 .iso file (the originally downloaded file linuxmint-17.3-cinnamon-64bit.iso + VBoxGuestAdditions.iso), some .vbox files (short text files) and .vdi files (11 GB).

Comment: Did you install VCD in the host or the VM?

Comment: @Richie086 : Ignore previous comment. I installed virtual clonedrive, right clicked on VBoxGuestAdditions.iso and created an E: drive. I get the folder structure inside E: (64bit, 32bit), but the folders look empty. I think I'll just start again from scratch and note down all the steps required to recreate the config of the VM, so I can just copy/paste them the next time this happens. I'm using it to edit a theme in WordPress so the process is quite straightforward. Fortunately installing in Linux can be done from the command line, which makes it much easier than in Windows!

Comment: Your second answer: I installed VCD on the host

Comment: Make sure you download the extensions for virtual box from this page https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Comment: Finally managed to install extensions. Error message talked about admin rights. Right-click offered no option to launch  the executable in admin mode. Had to open a cmd windows in admin mode and launch with command line. I am now reinstalling from scratch. VirtualBox is really cute when things work, but when they go astray it's hell!

Comment: Strange.  At least your problem was resolved.  Did my suggestion of using VCD help at all?